# How to prevent default route to redirect to "#/"?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I visit `http://localhost/` it redirects me to `http://localhost/#/`. Is it possible to prevent this and stay at `http://localhost/` and load a default component when you request root? I need to use `HashLocationStrategy` because I'm also using ASP.NET Core MVC and its routes in the same project.

```
export const HomeRoutes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
];

const MyRoutes: Routes = [
    ...HomeRoutes
];

export const MyRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(MyRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using hash strategy change your export statement with this line

```
export const MyRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(MyRoutes, { useHash: false });
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I need to use HashLocationStrategy since I'm also using ASP.NET Core MVC in the same project.